# Rails3: Logs show crash on `rake jobs:work`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

My Rails logs (pulled from Heroku) keep showing the app trying to run

rake jobs:work

but I'm not running Delayed Job.  (Not that I can remember).

Is there another reason Rails would run rake jobs:work?  Where should I look for it in the app files?

Here's the error lines

```
2011-12-02T19:40:27+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-12-02T19:40:27+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from created to starting
2011-12-02T19:40:30+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Starting process with command `rake jobs:work`
2011-12-02T19:40:30+00:00 app[worker.2]: (in /app)
2011-12-02T19:40:31+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from starting to up
2011-12-02T19:40:31+00:00 app[worker.2]: rake aborted!
2011-12-02T19:40:31+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Process exited
2011-12-02T19:40:32+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from up to crashed
2011-12-02T19:49:04+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-12-02T19:49:07+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `rake jobs:work`
2011-12-02T19:49:07+00:00 app[worker.1]: (in /app)
2011-12-02T19:49:07+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Thanks

Comment: are you running a heroku cron (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cron) or a delayed job worker? (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job)

Comment: yes i am running cron, hourly.  the error seems to happen outside of the hourly cron job, though.  (My cron runs at :03 past the hour, and this error runs at all times.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure off hand why this is happening but i guess you could just scale down the workers on Heroku to prevent it from happening again:

```
heroku scale worker=0
```

Comment: But if i scale the workers to zero, my app won't run, right?  its an app that's in production for a client.

Comment: Ahh yeah if you have other tasks using workers then this won't fix your problem at all. You deffo don't have a jobs.rake file sitting around somewhere in your repository at all? If you run `Rake -T` from the command line locally, there are no clues as to what the task is?